# data modeling & security rules advice firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am trying to model 2 concepts in firestore and also associate

```
collection: users
key/document_id: email
document: profile info

collection: topics
key/document_id: random
document: metadata with a field indicating email of user (to use for lookups)
```

My goal is to

- "reference" topics in users for easy lookups, but not sure how to do
  it other than a sub collection.
- Based on email which will be passed as part of auth, I want to have security rule to allow writes in collection only on path, field
  based on email

Are both of above feasible in Firebase. Appreciate any pointers!

Comment: We are usually structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries?

Comment: query user profile, query topics like a feed based on interests

Answer (score 2):

***Preamble**: There isn't ONE and only ONE correct approach in NoSQL data modelling*

Your approach seems valid, however I  would suggest the following adaptations:

#### "Reference topics in users for easy lookups":

To "reference topics in users for easy lookups" you could duplicate the list of `topics` in an array in the `user` profile. You will then be able to use `array-contains` (and other [array membership](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) methods) for your queries. (Note however the limitation of the `in` operator).

Advantage of this approach: you only need to query one document to get all the topics of a user. Possible drawback: there is a limit on the size for a document (and for a single field value) which is maximum 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes), see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits).

You can easily keep in sync the `topics` array and the `topics` sub-collection by combining a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) and the `arrayUnion()` and `arrayRemove()` [methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

---

#### Use the user ID instead of the email for doc Ids and Security Rules:

Instead of using the email as the `users` collection document ID and using it in Security Rules, use the user ID. See the examples in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions).